# Dual boot centOS and Win7

Tags: windows-7, centos, multi-boot

I posted this on stackoverflow, but it looks like superuser would be more appropriate.

I have a CentOS 5 machine that runs Windows 7 as a dual boot. CentOS is the main OS and each OS is set up in a specific hard drive. This was set up before I joined the company and I don't really have need to run Windows now.

My question is: can I, from CentOS, reformat the Windows HD, change GRUB settings and get the HD to be available on CentOS? Happy to provide more info if this helps.

Many thanks for your help and apologies if this is a very simple issue... I don't want to blindly test things on this machine as it is used on a daily basis by several users.